# pgfplots: find the intersection point of two curves and determine the y value of the intersection point

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, axis, intersections

##### Thank you for reading my question!

---

#### Introduction

Now I want to draw a picture, in which I need to calculate the **intersection** point of the two curves and determine whether the y value of the intersection point is zero. If it is not zero, I need to draw a straight line perpendicular to the x-axis through the point.
I'm going to use a loop(`foreach`) to complete the operation, but now I have a problem when getting the total number of loops. The **total number** of loops should be the **total number** of `intersections`, but now it seems that the total number of `intersections` is not correctly copied to the macro`\t`.

---

Here is my code:  ***My environment is VSCode + TexLive + LaTeX Workshop***

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\sigmarayleigh{1}
    \def\gaussmean{4}
    \def\gaussvar{1.5}
    \def\xmin{0}
    \def\xmax{8}
    \def\ymin{0}
    \def\ymax{0.7}
    \begin{axis}[title = Fig1,xlabel = $Voltage$,ylabel = $Probability Density$,xmin = \xmin, xmax = \xmax, ymin = \ymin, ymax = \ymax, grid = both, legend pos = north east]
        \coordinate (O) at (\xmin,\ymin);
        \coordinate (X) at (\xmax,\ymin);
        \coordinate (Y) at (\xmin,\ymax);
        \addplot[name path = rayleigh, domain = 0:8, samples = 100, color = black, dashed, line width = 1pt]{x*exp(-x^2/(2*\sigmarayleigh^2))/(\sigmarayleigh^2)};
        \addplot[name path = gauss, domain = 0:8, samples = 100, color = black, line width = 1pt]{1/(sqrt(2*pi*\gaussvar))*exp(-(x-\gaussmean)^2/(2*\gaussvar))};
        \path [name intersections={of=rayleigh and gauss, name = ii, total=\t}];
        \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{
            \typeout{Total intersections: \s};
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**I'm going to test if my loop works but this code doesn't compile successfully.**
The following is the compile log:
[image]

---

Then I made a simple modification to my code, replacing the `\t` with a fixed number 9, and then this code can run successfully. The modified code is as follows:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\sigmarayleigh{1}
    \def\gaussmean{4}
    \def\gaussvar{1.5}
    \def\xmin{0}
    \def\xmax{8}
    \def\ymin{0}
    \def\ymax{0.7}
    \begin{axis}[title = Fig1,xlabel = $Voltage$,ylabel = $Probability Density$,xmin = \xmin, xmax = \xmax, ymin = \ymin, ymax = \ymax, grid = both, legend pos = north east]
        \coordinate (O) at (\xmin,\ymin);
        \coordinate (X) at (\xmax,\ymin);
        \coordinate (Y) at (\xmin,\ymax);
        \addplot[name path = rayleigh, domain = 0:8, samples = 100, color = black, dashed, line width = 1pt]{x*exp(-x^2/(2*\sigmarayleigh^2))/(\sigmarayleigh^2)};
        \addplot[name path = gauss, domain = 0:8, samples = 100, color = black, line width = 1pt]{1/(sqrt(2*pi*\gaussvar))*exp(-(x-\gaussmean)^2/(2*\gaussvar))};
        \path [name intersections={of=rayleigh and gauss, name = ii, total=\t}];
        \foreach \s in {1,...,9}{
            \typeout{Total intersections: \s};
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The following is the compile log:
[image]
It seems that **`\t`** is not assigned a value in my code. 
Is there something wrong with my usage of `intersections`?

Comment: Welcome! `\foreach  [expand list=true] \s in ...` so the `\t` is expanded before it is used for the loop. And you have a spurious `;` in the loop which is responsible for the `null font` warnings when you substitute `9`. `\typeout{Total intersections: \s};`  ->  `\typeout{Total intersections: \s}`.